# Prepending an unknown amount of database fields to array

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have a database with the following structure

```
user_id | cat_name | cat_slug | parent_id
-------------------------------------------
Tools   | tools    |     0    |
2       |Chainsaws |chainsaws |     1
```

etc

My end goal is to essentially have an array that has a breadcrumb trail of sorts that shows the category path, it could have anywhere from no parents to 5 levels of category parenting.

I was able to kind of get what I want.. with a few errors along the way. I keep getting a `Trying to get property of non-object` error. Althrough all my other attempts at returning values have failed.

My solution outputs my (semi - desired) effect underneath the errors, and with additional category breaks ( symbolized by ">" ). I was just hoping someone could help me clean it up, because I'm at a breaking point, after going about this for a few hours with no solution.

**Model**

```
function get_parent_trail($parent_id){



    if ( $parent_id != 0 && $parent_id){

        $parent_trail = array();

        for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i ++ ) {


            $this -> db -> select ( '*' );
            $this -> db -> from ( 'categories' );
            $this -> db -> where ( 'cat_id' , $parent_id );
            $query = $this -> db -> get() -> row();

            array_unshift( $parent_trail, $query->cat_name ) ;

            $parent_id = $query->parents;

        }

        foreach( $parent_trail as $ti ) {
            if ( $ti ) {
                echo "<strong>" . $ti . "</strong> > ";
            }
        }

    } else {

        echo "<span style='color:red;'>No Parent Category</span>";

    }

}
```

**View**

```
    <table class='admin_table'>
        <thead>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Parent</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
       foreach($cats as $cat){
        echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>" . $cat['cat_id'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $cat['cat_name'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>";
           $this -> categories -> get_parent_trail( $cat['parents'] );
           echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
       }
        ?>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

**NOTE:**
The '4' in the for loop doesn't need to be dynamic as I've set a hard limit of up to 5 categories, though there has been no need to go that far into sub-categories.

I also have an additional ">" at the end of my list, which I need to get rid of, I know the reason my way doesn't work, it's just the closest solution I could find for the time being.

**End Result**

Basically,  I want my end result to look like;

With 2 'levels' of parent categories

```
id | name                |      slug             |        Parent(s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Electric Chainsaws  |   electric-chainsaws  |   Tools > Chainsaws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling and several bottles of very strong rum, I was able to finally figure this out. I'm still relatively novice at using codeigniter so my solution may have some unnecessary steps to it, but I feel obliged to share what I learned. Here is my entire function.

```
function get_parent_trail($parent_id){

    if ( $parent_id != 0 && $parent_id){

        $parent_trail = array();
        $inc = 0;

        for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i ++ ) {

            if ( $parent_id != 0 && $parent_id){
                $this -> db -> select ( '*' );
                $this -> db -> from ( 'categories' );
                $this -> db -> where ( 'cat_id' , $parent_id );
                $query = $this -> db -> get();
                $row = $query -> row_array();

                array_unshift( $parent_trail, $row['cat_name'] ) ;

                $parent_id = $row['parents'];
            } else {
                $inc++;
            }

        }

        $popOff = array_pop($parent_trail);

        if ($inc > 2 ){
            echo "<span style='color:red;'>No Parent Category</span>";
        }


        $string  = '';
        foreach( $parent_trail as $ti ) {
            if ( $ti ) {
                $string .=  $ti.' > ';
            }
        }

        (string) $test = substr($string, 0, -2);
        echo $test;

    } else {

        echo "<span style='color:red;'>No Parent Category</span>";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is build a recursive function. 
Example of this would be:

```
function factorial($number) 
{ 
    if ($number < 2) 
    { 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
    } 
}
```